Combinatorics(chessboard problem)
In a chessboard, find the number of ways to select 3 continuous squares in the same direction or 2 squares in one direction and 1 square attached in the other direction .
I was confused as to how to approach it.
Like should I make cases of different possibilities of 3 squares or some other method?
And what should I do if it was an n×n square?

Welcome to the forum ! Pl. note that you are required to first edit in  what efforts you have made and where you are stuck, also what topics you have studied, so that pinpointed guidance can be given.

Thanks a lot sir, I've tried to edit to what I'm confused about. I'm new in this so, I'm not sure how to ask questions but I've tried to make it as clear as I could.

can you define "3 continuous squares"? do 3 diagonal squares count?

Adjacent ones. Not diagonals

In the first case, all three squares are aligned vertically. In this case, there are 6 ways to select the position in each column, and 8 columns, hence there are $6 \cdot 8 = 48$ combinations.
In the second case, all three squares are aligned horizontally. By symmetry, there are also 48 combinations.
In the last case, two squares are aligned in one direction and the other is adjacent in the other direction. There are 4 ways to make such a structure. For each of these structures, there is exactly one way to place it on the chessboard for each 2x2 region. There are $7 \cdot 7 = 49$ unique 2x2 regions on the chessboard, hence this case counts for $4 \cdot 49 = 196$ combinations.
The total number of combinations is $ 48 + 48 + 196 = 292 $

Thanks a lot! I could find the 1st case but I was totally dumbfounded in the second case of 2 sq in one direction and 1 in the other. Your answer is op! Thenksss again. :)
